# cartesian product of overlapping list of intervals

Tags: python

I have two lists of lists consisting of interval the real line

```
I = [[8,12], [18,24], [3,5]]
J = [[7,10], [2,6], [18,22]]
```

I want to to gernerate a list that contains the pairs of intervals from I and J that overlap. For example one element of the list would be [[8,12],[7,10]]. I have a loop that does this

```
res=[]
for i in range(len(I)):
    des=[]
    for j in range(len(J)):
        if (I[i][1]<=J[j][1] and I[i][1]>=J[j][0])   or (J[j][1]<=I[i][1] and J[j][1]>=I[i][0]):

             z=[I[i],J[j]]
             res.append(z)
```

which yields

```
res=[[[8, 12], [7, 10]], [[18, 24], [18, 22]], [[3, 5], [2, 6]]]
```

but I am trying to find a cleaner more efficient version

It is possible to have overlapping intervals in each seperate list. For example we could have

```
I= [ [2,5], [1,4] ]
```

and

```
J= [[3,7], [10,12]]
```

in this case the list the result would be

```
[ [[1,4], [3,7]], [[2,5],[3,7]]
```

Comment: There are some information missing. e.g,  Can there be multiple overlapping blocks? Can there be no overlapping blocks? How should it be stored in those case?

Comment: @Prophecies. Hopefully I answered your question in my edits. I assume you mean overlapping blocks within each original list

Comment: Thanks for clarification and it looks like @Keith has answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be made a little more readable by using `enumerate` to pull the index and values out at the same time. Also, semantically the number pairs might be better described as tuples.

```
I = [(8,12), (18,24), (3,5)]
J = [(7,10), (2,6), (18,22)]

def overlap(I, J):
    res=[]
    for i, ival in enumerate(I):
        for j, jval in enumerate(J):
            if (ival[1]<=jval[1] and ival[1]>=jval[0]) or (jval[1]<=ival[1] and jval[1]>=ival[0]):
                 z = (ival, jval)
                 res.append(z)
    return res

res = overlap(I, J)
print(res)
assert res == [((8, 12), (7, 10)), ((18, 24), (18, 22)), ((3, 5), (2, 6))]
```

But since the index doesn't have to be used, this can be simplified even further by just looping over the values.

```
def overlap(I, J):
    res=[]
    for ival in I:
        for jval in J:
            if (ival[1]<=jval[1] and ival[1]>=jval[0]) or (jval[1]<=ival[1] and jval[1]>=ival[0]):
                 z = (ival, jval)
                 res.append(z)
    return res
```